# Build DataGridView table without a source?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I have never managed to get DataGridView working as I needed, but I am back at it again and hoping that I can get it figured out. I currently have a class where I store a lot of data about each individual Support Ticket that comes into our software, but I want to only display some of this data on a DataGridView.

The class looks as follows...

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string TicketID { get; set; }
    public string DeptID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastResponse { get; set; }
    public IPAddress IP { get; set; }
}
```

I want to build a table that shows Name/Message/Priority or some combination of these values, but definitely not all of them. Is there any way that I can simply just build the table data from scratch rather than having to supply it a data source?

Here is my test code implementing the suggestion below but I get "No Row can be added to DataGridView control that does not have columns".

```
                WHMCS x = new WHMCS();
                List<WHMCS.Ticket> Tickets = new List<WHMCS.Ticket>();
                Tickets = x.Get_Tickets();

                KryptonDataGridView dgv = new KryptonDataGridView();
                content1.Controls.Add(dgv);

                foreach (var tix in Tickets)
                {
                    var objArr = new object[] {tix.Priority, tix.Subject};
                    dgv.Rows.Add(objArr);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add rows manually by converting your Ticket class to an object array, using the fields you are interested in, then adding the array to the dataGrid. Something like

```
foreach(var ticket in AllTickets){
    var objArr = new object[]{ticket.Id, ticket.DeptId...};
    dataGrid.Rows.Add(objArr);
}
```

Make sure the types in the array correspond to the types expected by each column, and you will also have to propagate values back to your data source manually if they are editable by the user.

In response to your comment:
Before adding rows, populate the dataGrid with columns:

```
_colId = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
           Name = "Id",
           HeaderText = Id.CreationDate,
           AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None,
           Width = 150,
           ReadOnly = true,
        };
//...

dataGrid.Columns.Add(_colId);
dataGrid.Columns.Add( other columns... );
```

Use whatever properties you need on each column.

Comment: I gave it a try exactly as suggested but got the error "No Row can be added to DataGridView control that does not have columns". I updated my original post with the code but do you know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your not using the datasource I believe you have to explicitly add the columns first. As you know the columns you want to be showing, before your foreach loop you use:

```
dgv.Columns.Add([Column Info]);
```

This method will allow you to explicitly create the columns you will be adding to when you add the row information.